# Hide non-local "Ships to you" listings in Facebook Marketplace?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketplace

I use Facebook Marketplace alongside Craigslist as a source for buying **LOCAL** items in person.

The **Today's Picks for You** feature is sometimes good for surfacing items I might be interested it.

[image: Ships to you items]

However, recently many or most of these items have become **Ships to you** items that are not local.

I am never going to buy these non-local shipping items. I never want to see them suggested.

How can I hide every item that is not available for local pickup?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I am currently using is to "Sort By" "Distance" "Nearest First"

This gets rid of all the "ships to you", but also presents a lot of items that don't match my search term.

Facebook gonna Facebook.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in all FB clients.  FBsux.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the URL parameter `?deliveryMethod=local_pick_up` filters to only Local Pickup items.

> https://www.facebook.com/marketplace?deliveryMethod=local_pick_up

This method can filter "all items" to only Local Pickup, without selecting a category. It doesn't seem to be available via the user interface, so add the URL parameter manually or click the link above.